# How to update man pages database?

Tags: linux, manpage

Man is missing many entries(almost all system calls). It also doesn't work with --update argument. What is the issue?
When I tried for 'open', It showed manual for Perl's open.

Comment: `sudo mandb` will do. (watch out for straycats) Can take several minutes to complete on large installs.  I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

`man` uses predefined search path or colon separated `MANPATH`.

It is meaningless to update "database". You could rebuild a search cache for `apropos` or like commands, but it doesn't influence browsing installed man pages.

If your MANPATH is OK and you miss some pages it means you haven't installed them to the system ))